# Chrome Remote Debugging gives me blank screen

Tags: google-chrome, remote-debugging

I use remote debugging on raspian with chromium(92.0.4515.98~buster-rpt2) and it works just fine.
However, if I want to do the same on ubuntu with chrome(100.0.4896.127-1) or chromium(101.0.4951.64) I just get a blank page. I don't even get "Inspectable pages", just blank screen () nothing more. Do I need to change any settings? Does anyone know why that is? Has it anything to do with the older version on raspian?